# ERROR: "ERROR: Failed to fetch page due to: HttpConnectionTimeout" On Twitter Card validator

Tags: java

No changes to site or permissions.
No issues with .htaccess.
No blocking with robots.txt.
No changes to SEO or cache.
Cleared cache.
URL is plublic via ping, traceroute, etc.
URL resolves with iframely.com 5
URL has twitter card mark up and are valid

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this eventually? It keeps refusing my website (https://cryptowings.io).